# Get user current location in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\MultiTenantModelTrait;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Attendance extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, MultiTenantModelTrait;

    public $table = 'attendances';

    protected $dates = [
        'time_end',
        'time_start',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'time_end',
        'time_start',
        'place_start',
        'place_end',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function setTimeStartAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['time_start'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;
    }

    public function getTimeStartAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->format(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format')) : null;
    }

    public function setTimeEndAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['time_end'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;
    }

    public function getTimeEndAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->format(config('panel.date_format') . ' ' . config('panel.time_format')) : null;
    }

    public function getDateStartAttribute()
    {
        return $this->time_start ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->time_start)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;
    }

    public function getTotalTimeAttribute()
    {
        $time_start = $this->time_start ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->time_start) : null;
        $time_end = $this->time_end ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->time_end) : null;

        return $this->time_end ? $time_end->diffInSeconds($time_start) : 0;
    }
    public function getTotalTimeChartAttribute()
    {
        return $this->total_time ? round($this->total_time/3600, 2) : 0;
    }
}
```

This is my attendance model using laravel. I would like to do when a user clicks on the button, the time_start and location_start values are recieved and saved into database. This model is ok with time values and I don't know how to write for location values. Someone please help me in writing to get location values.

Answer (score 4):

you can't get users current location by php or any back-end language if you want to get location you have 2 ways:

1. getting location by using services that give you location of IP address of user like this:

   ```
    <?php
    $user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
    $country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
    $city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
   ```
2. getting users current location by javascript and sending it as a param to model like this:

   ```
    <script>
    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }

   function showPosition(position) {
     var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! I will try it.